# Cannot publish Asp.Net Core application on IIS

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to publish my app on IIS. It gives the below error while clicking on **Test Settings**.

> There was an error while performing this operation. Details: Invalid
>   application path.

**Steps:**

1. Open IIS.
2. Right-click **Default Web Site** and select **Add Application**.
3. Give **Alias** and select **DefaultAppPool** as application pool and select the physical path **MyProject\bin\Release\PublishOutput**.
4. Click on **Test Settings**.

But If I try the below steps, I'm successfully able to publish my app.

1. Open IIS.
2. Right-click **Sites** and then select **Add Web Site**.
3. Give **Alias** and select **DefaultAppPool** as application pool and select the physical path **MyProject\bin\Release\PublishOutput**.
4. Click on **Test Settings**.

Please let me know if I'm doing anything wrong.

IIS 6, Asp.Net Core 2.0.1, Visual Studio 2017 version 15.6.6

**Update:**

I tried to enable logs in the application. the log file is generated when I try to browse the application. It says **Application startup exception: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unknown database 'spardb'**. But the `spardb` database exists. So what could be the possible root cause?

**Logs**

> warn:
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.EphemeralXmlRepository[50]
>         Using an in-memory repository. Keys will not be persisted to storage. warn:
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[59]
>         Neither user profile nor HKLM registry available. Using an ephemeral key repository. Protected data will be unavailable when
>   application exits. info:
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[58]
>         Creating key {98bbcd98-dbcb-4f7e-855d-d2b91729cfb1} with creation date 2018-06-27 12:42:47Z, activation date 2018-06-27
>   12:42:47Z, and expiration date 2018-09-25 12:42:47Z. warn:
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
>         No XML encryptor configured. Key {98bbcd98-dbcb-4f7e-855d-d2b91729cfb1} may be persisted to storage in
>   unencrypted form. Application startup exception:
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unknown database
>   'spardb'    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   at
>   MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.<SwitchAuthenticationAsync>d__58.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ServerSession.cs:line
>   342
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.<ConnectAsync>d__56.MoveNext() in
>   C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ServerSession.cs:line
>   256
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.<GetSessionAsync>d__0.MoveNext() in
>   C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ConnectionPool.cs:line
>   92
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.<CreateSessionAsync>d__77.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlConnection.cs:line
>   355
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.<OpenAsync>d__19.MoveNext() in
>   C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlConnection.cs:line
>   160
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open() in
>   C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlConnection.cs:line
>   137    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean
>   errorsExpected)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel
>   isolationLevel)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.MySqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState
>   state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.BeginTransaction(DatabaseFacade
>   databaseFacade, IsolationLevel isolationLevel)    at
>   Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Uow.DbContextEfCoreTransactionStrategy.CreateDbContext[TDbContext](String
>   connectionString, IDbContextResolver dbContextResolver)    at
>   Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Uow.EfCoreUnitOfWork.GetOrCreateDbContext[TDbContext](Nullable`1
>   multiTenancySide)    at
>   Nec.Spar.EntityFrameworkCore.Seed.SeedHelper.WithDbContext[TDbContext](IIocResolver
>   iocResolver, Action`1 contextAction) in
>   C:\Spar\FoodKioskSolution\Nec.Spar\src\Nec.Spar.EntityFrameworkCore\EntityFrameworkCore\Seed\SeedHelper.cs:line
>   43    at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.ForEach(Action`1 action)
>
>   at Abp.AbpBootstrapper.Initialize()    at
>   Abp.AspNetCore.AbpApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseAbp(IApplicationBuilder
>   app, Action`1 optionsAction)    at
>   Nec.Spar.Web.Host.Startup.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,
>   IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) in
>   C:\Spar\FoodKioskSolution\Nec.Spar\src\Nec.Spar.Web.Host\Startup\Startup.cs:line
>   102
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder
>   app)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication() crit:
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[6]
>         Application startup exception MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unknown database
>   'spardb'    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   at
>   MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.<SwitchAuthenticationAsync>d__58.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ServerSession.cs:line
>   342
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   MySqlConnector.Core.ServerSession.<ConnectAsync>d__56.MoveNext() in
>   C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ServerSession.cs:line
>   256
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   MySqlConnector.Core.ConnectionPool.<GetSessionAsync>d__0.MoveNext() in
>   C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ConnectionPool.cs:line
>   92
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.<CreateSessionAsync>d__77.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlConnection.cs:line
>   355
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.<OpenAsync>d__19.MoveNext() in
>   C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlConnection.cs:line
>   160
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open() in
>   C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlConnection.cs:line
>   137    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean
>   errorsExpected)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel
>   isolationLevel)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.MySqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState
>   state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.BeginTransaction(DatabaseFacade
>   databaseFacade, IsolationLevel isolationLevel)    at
>   Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Uow.DbContextEfCoreTransactionStrategy.CreateDbContext[TDbContext](String
>   connectionString, IDbContextResolver dbContextResolver)    at
>   Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Uow.EfCoreUnitOfWork.GetOrCreateDbContext[TDbContext](Nullable`1
>   multiTenancySide)    at
>   Nec.Spar.EntityFrameworkCore.Seed.SeedHelper.WithDbContext[TDbContext](IIocResolver
>   iocResolver, Action`1 contextAction) in
>   C:\Spar\FoodKioskSolution\Nec.Spar\src\Nec.Spar.EntityFrameworkCore\EntityFrameworkCore\Seed\SeedHelper.cs:line
>   43    at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.ForEach(Action`1 action)
>
>   at Abp.AbpBootstrapper.Initialize()    at
>   Abp.AspNetCore.AbpApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseAbp(IApplicationBuilder
>   app, Action`1 optionsAction)    at
>   Nec.Spar.Web.Host.Startup.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,
>   IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) in
>   C:\Spar\FoodKioskSolution\Nec.Spar\src\Nec.Spar.Web.Host\Startup\Startup.cs:line
>   102
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder
>   app)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
>   Hosting environment: Production Content root path:
>   C:\Published\PublishOutput Now listening on: http://localhost:4725
>   Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down. info:
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
>         Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost/swaggar   info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
>         Request finished in 168.6654ms 500 text/html; charset=utf-8 info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
>         Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost/swaggar   info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
>         Request finished in 0.363ms 500 text/html; charset=utf-8 info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
>         Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost/swaggar   info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
>         Request finished in 0.2192ms 500 text/html; charset=utf-8 info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
>         Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost/swaggar   info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
>         Request finished in 0.3408ms 500 text/html; charset=utf-8 info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
>         Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost/swaggar   info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
>         Request finished in 0.2087ms 500 text/html; charset=utf-8 info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
>         Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost/swaggar   info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
>         Request finished in 0.3917ms 500 text/html; charset=utf-8 info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
>         Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost/swaggar   info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
>         Request finished in 0.3248ms 500 text/html; charset=utf-8 info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
>         Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost/swaggar   info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
>         Request finished in 0.3079ms 500 text/html; charset=utf-8 info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
>         Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost/swaggar   info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
>         Request finished in 0.2387ms 500 text/html; charset=utf-8 info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
>         Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://127.0.0.1:4725/SWAGGAR/iisintegration  0 info:
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
>         Request finished in 0.4856ms 500 text/html; charset=utf-8 Application is shutting down...

Comment: What happens when you try to add a virtual directory instead?  There could be a number of reasons for this error.  The connection string could be one, security issues could be another (firewall closed for DB port?); username/password issues.  There could also be problems with assigning correct security privileges to the website directory for the IIS user account.

Comment: @Phill it allows me to create virtual directory